# Friendly URLs via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I read lots of tutorials and articles about Friendly URLs through htaccess file, but probably I am missing something.. Thus, I have some questions in order to understand..if someone can help me to clear these out, please!
First of all, before adding any rule to htaccess file,
1. Should I have links like article.php?article_id=1 or the friendly urls I want inside into my files, like: 2016/05/article_name  ???
2. I found I link here through another post, that gives a web tool in order to give the rule of the htaccess file: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php
So, I placed my actual 'ugly' link and gave me right rule to write in htaccess file.

Now, I have uploaded the htaccess file and I am navigating to my website.. If I have the 'ugly' links I can see everything correctly! While I am pressing the friendly url manually there was to issues:
    First, I could not see the website's css and javascripts files.. I put the absolute path according to an article, so I guess I am fine with that (is that correct?).
    Second, If I press a link let's say the logo, in order to go back to home page, it keeps the rule of htaccess and navigate me to "not found page".. cause the link is something like that: mywebsite.gr/2016/05/index.php, but year and month does not actually exists ...

I would like to have a rule in order to keep the same articles links (I do not have problems about the other links, categories, menus and so on.. just the links of articles). The link I have now is (after all I see and understood):
article.php?article_id=1&year=2016&month=05&name=test-1
and want to have:
mysite.gr/2016/05/test-1.html

*I guess I should mention that the Domain NS does not change yet, and I am working through the temporary link that host provides me.. something like: linux.41.24.23.4.server.gr   ... and so on

thanks a lot in advance!! (and sorry for the possible duplicate..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution... not sure if it is the best one..

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([a-z0-9\-]+)\/?.html$ category.php?file=$1&year=$2&month=$3&art_name=$4 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

in order to show my links this way:

```
mydomain.com.gr/2016/06/this-is-an-article.html
```

of course inside my website, I slit the article name coming from my DB, in order to add the middle slashes and replace any other symbol with 'nothing':

```
$art_name = "this is an article!";
$art_name = str_replace('!','',$art_name);
$art_name = str_replace(',','',$art_name);
$art_name = str_replace(' ','-',$art_name);
```

The final link inside my website is:

```
<a href="<?php echo $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$art_name.'.html'; ?>">click me</a>
```

Furthermore, about the other links: CSS - Js - a tags and so on, as long as I understood there are some options in order to work properly:
You could use Absolute path, or start your links like this (with forward slash in the beginning):

```
<link href="**/**main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it's working like an absolute path I believe, cause the file is seeing the root folder (for example for me is localhost - I am working locally with xampp)

I believe I helped someone who have the same questions..